# J query click function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Html code that is below

```
<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzonePreview"></div>
```

within above div i am create some more divs by j query code after some processing. Below div i am created dynamically by jquery

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-complete">
<a class="dz-cover" href="javascript:undefined;" data-id="73" data-dz-cover="">Make Cover</a>
</div>
```

So the now code look like by inspect element

```
<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzonePreview">
    <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-complete">
    <a class="dz-cover" href="javascript:undefined;" data-id="73" data-dz-cover="">Make Cover</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I write some j query code for click event `Make Cover`  my code is below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.dz-cover').click(function () {

       alert('dddd');
    });
});
```

But when i click nothing is happening my j query code is not working what i do where i am wrong

Comment: Did you make sure you don't have any js error (with chorme dev tools in console) ?

Comment: That code by itself would definitely work. Is jQuery loading correctly? Is `$(document).ready()` firing? Is the markup being altered at all before that code runs?

Comment: yes my `$(document).ready()` is firing i think problem is due to my html code  is created by j query . when i click DOM have nothing that element in which i am clicking but i refresh the page it works fine

Comment: If the link exposes no href, I recommend you to use a button instead of a link.

Comment: `$('a.dz-cover').on('click',function () {

       alert('dddd');
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the element you're trying to click doesn't exist on document ready, you'll have to use `.on()` to select it.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

In your case

```
$( "#dropzonePreview" ).on( "click", "a.dz-cover", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks it is Working

Answer (score 0):

Please use the class only for the selector section as you have defined a class of ".dz-cover".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dz-cover").click(function () {

       alert("dddd");
    });
});
```